# Join data on a table based on a relationship table

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables in my database, "Fact" and "Fact_Cause", Here's the table structure:

**Fact**: ID(PK), Name, Date

**Fact_Cause**: IDCauseFact(FK -> Fact(ID)), IDEffectFact(FK -> Fact(ID))

What I want is a resultant table with this format

*Cause* |  *Effect*

Each column containing the Name of the corresponding Fact.

Could you guide me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally worked it out, here's the SQL query:

```
SELECT cause.Name AS 'Cause', effect.Name AS 'Effect' 
FROM Fact_Cause c
INNER JOIN Fact cause ON c.IDCauseFact = cause.ID
INNER JOIN Fact effect ON c.IDEffectCause = effect.Id
```

I was failing on the joins and the aliases :)